# Enabling API permission on the PayPal sandbox website

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

As per title, I'm unable to find the settings to enable API permissions on the PayPal sandbox site.

I login using my sandbox credentials, can navigate through the PayPal replica website but I cannot find such settings

On the live account it's straightforward though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sandbox environment, please login www.sandbox.paypal.com by your sandbox account, then open https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-api-grant-authorization to grant permission to other accounts.